# Vim remap F10 key

Tags: vim, freebsd

I use Vim 7.3 on FreeBSD. I connect to this machine through Putty. When working on Vim, I'm unable to remap <kbd>F10</kbd> key to do something I want. In my .vimrc, I did the following:

```
nmap <F10> :!ls<CR>
```

Then I did, "source $MYVIMRC" to load the changes in .vimrc. When I press <kbd>F10</kbd> after this, it prints ^[[21~ instead of the executing the map. I tried all combination of `noremap` but nothing works.

Remapping this to other function keys is not an option because they are mapped for other uses.

Just FYI, in Putty configuration options, under Terminal->Keyboard, I have set the "Function keys and keypad" option to "Linux".

Any suggestion to get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your termcap/terminfo and/or the value of `$TERM` you're using are preventing Vim from recognizing the character sequence your terminal is sending for F10 as F10.

The easy workaround is to map the character sequence. In your .vimrc, type the following:

```
nmap <CTRL-V><F10> :!ls<CR>
```

Where `<CTRL-V><F10>` is pressing CTRL-V followed by F10. This will result in something like `^[[21~` appearing in your buffer. That's okay, this mapping should work (at least with that terminal).

The "right" fix would be to change the value of `$TERM`, your termcap or terminfo database such that Vim knows that `^[[21~` is F10. Setting `$TERM` to `xterm` may work.

Comment: Setting the `$TERM` to `xterm` works like a charm. Thanks Laurence.